# PHP square brackets for arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to send multiple files with the [Phaxio API](https://www.phaxio.com/docs/api/send/sendFax/), and I can't get past their `[]` notation.

In order to pass multiple files, the parameters necessary that DO work are:

This works:

```
"filename[]"=>"@file1.pdf", "@file2.pdf", "@file3.pdf"
```

How would I go about generating the right side (the values) in an actual array such as $files = array("file1.pdf", "$file2.pdf", "file3.pdf");

The syntax is just not working out for me so far, I've tried:

These do not work:

```
"filename[]"=>array("@file1.pdf", "@file2.pdf", "@file3.pdf")
```

OR

```
"filename"=>array("@file1.pdf", "@file2.pdf", "@file3.pdf")
```

OR

```
"filename"=>"@file1.pdf, @file2.pdf, @file3.pdf"
```

I am using PHP 5.3.10

The notation that does work generates something along these lines:

```
[filename[]]=>"@file1.pdf",
[0]=>"@file2.pdf",
[1]=>"@file3.pdf"
```

---

@Halcyon :

I tried the following:

```
$files =array("filename" => array("@uploads/invite_template.pdf", "@uploads/2.pdf"));

$data = array(
            "to"=>"$faxToNumber", 
            "filename[]"=>$files
             );
```

I can't just add the array to it as it's an associative array (ex:)

```
$data = array(
            "to"=>"$faxToNumber", 
             $files
             );
```

I can just append to the data array and that'll make it work but.. how do I make it work with the way you are encoding it?

This works properly so far:

```
$data += array("filename[0]"=>"@uploads/1.pdf");
$data += array("filename[1]"=>"@uploads/2.pdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is just a URL encoded body it should look something like:

```
filename[]=value1&filename[]=value2&filename[]=value3
```

In PHP you can't do:

```
array(
    "filename[]" => "value1",
    "filename[]" => "value2"
)
```

Because you'd have a duplicate key. What you can do is:

```
array(
    "filename" => array("value1", "value2")
)
```

and encode it as above when sending.

---

This also works:

```
array(
    "filename[0]" => "value1",
    "filename[1]" => "value2",
    "filename[2]" => "value3"
)
```

Comment: If explicit indices are allowed by the receiving server, `http_build_query` can do that.

Comment: I'll edit at the top. Still getting wrecked in syntax.

Comment: Don't do `"filename[]" => array()`. The `[]` notation is part of the url encoding.